# Iterator in cconstructor - Vectors and Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class, iterator

I'm facing the following problem, I have this class:

```
class Foo {

  public:
    template<typename T>
    Foo(T begin, T end)
    : data(begin, end)
    {
       // implementation
    }

  private:
     std::vector<std::vector<double> > data; 
};
```

Internally I want vectors to be used, but I want to allow for both `std::vector` and `std::array` This will work when I pass in a vector, however, when I pass in a `std::array` I get a lot of errors.

Is it therefore possible to use the following method (Populating the "data") when passing in either an array or a vector? Sorry if this question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Which error you have? This works fine for me.

Comment: Probably because you can't assign `std::arrays` to `std::vectors`. But better post a representative code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want this:

```
template<typename Seq>
Foo(const Seq& seq)
: data(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq))
{
}
```

Then you can pass in any container that supports std::begin and end, even including C-style arrays.

Comment: This simplifies the syntax of instantiating Foo, but I don't think it solves his problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're getting errors when you pass iterators from a `std::array<std::array<double>>`. This is because the `std::array<double>` cannot be assigned to the `std::vector<double>`. You could populate data manually by doing something like this:

```
template<typename T>
Foo(T begin, T end)
{
    data.reserve(std::distance(begin, end));
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
        data.emplace_back(begin->begin(), begin->end());
    // implementation
}
```